# Trying to make this code in r more elegant and shorter if possible - R

Tags: r, mean

**A little background:** This is code to calculate the average distance a mouse called BOE 1 traveled during the study over the corse of 12 days, with 4 repetitions of the experiment each day. There are 19 mice tested in each data set.

**Problem:** I want to calculate the mean distance traveled for each mouse and put that in a table. What I have works, but I was curious if there was a way to make the following code shorter, and less repetitive.

**Options tried:**

```
mean(BOE.1Data$Distance.cm[BOE.1Data$Day == c(1,2, ect)]
mean(BOE.1Data$Distance.cm[BOE.1Data$Day == c(1|2| ect)]
mean(BOE.1Data$Distance.cm[BOE.1Data$Day == c(1&2& ect)]
```

None of these have worked for me.

**Code:**

```
Distance.1 = c(mean(BOE.1Data$Distance.cm[BOE.1Data$Day == 1]),
               mean(BOE.1Data$Distance.cm[BOE.1Data$Day == 2]), 
               mean(BOE.1Data$Distance.cm[BOE.1Data$Day == 3]),
               mean(BOE.1Data$Distance.cm[BOE.1Data$Day == 4]),
               mean(BOE.1Data$Distance.cm[BOE.1Data$Day == 5]),
               mean(BOE.1Data$Distance.cm[BOE.1Data$Day == 6]),
               mean(BOE.1Data$Distance.cm[BOE.1Data$Day == 7]), 
               mean(BOE.1Data$Distance.cm[BOE.1Data$Day == 8]), 
               mean(BOE.1Data$Distance.cm[BOE.1Data$Day == 9]), 
               mean(BOE.1Data$Distance.cm[BOE.1Data$Day == 10]), 
               mean(BOE.1Data$Distance.cm[BOE.1Data$Day == 11]), 
               mean(BOE.1Data$Distance.cm[BOE.1Data$Day == 12]))
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide a [MCVE]

Comment: This looks like you want `with(BOE.1Data, tapply(Distance.cm, Day, mean))` but without sample input and desired output it's hard to say for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using `by()`:

```
by(BOE.1Data$Distance.cm, BOE.1Data$Day, mean)
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach with `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(BOE.1Data)`), grouped by 'Day', we get the `mean` of 'Distance.cm'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(BOE.1Data)[, .(MeanDist = mean(Distance.cm)) , by = Day]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n <- numeric(length(12))
for (i in 1:12) {
    n[i] <- mean(BOE.1Data$Distance.cm[BOE.1Data$Day == i])
}
```

Comment: 1. You should avoid `for`-loops in R 2. Your code obviously doesn't work the way you thought it would.

Comment: I was taught that you _should_ use for loops to make the code shorter. I'm just trying to be helpful and offer up a way that I would go about the problem, but I am semi-new and so without the data to test the code on I cannot guarantee the accuracy of my code.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using `dplyr` and `magrittr`, used `arrange()` to make sure they are in order.

```
Distance.1 <- BOE.1Data %>% group_by(Day) %>%
      mutate(mean_dist=mean(Distance.cm)) %>%
      arrange(Day) %$% mean_dist
```